# does awaitTermination() makes program sleep

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, executorservice, executor

```
class SomeClass {

 void go() {

 //do stuff
shutdownAndAwaitTermination(pool);

System.exit(0);

    }    

public void shutdownAndAwaitTermination(ExecutorService pool) {
        pool.shutdown(); 
        try {
            logger.log(Level.INFO, "Waiting for existing tasks to terminate");
            if (!pool.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
                pool.shutdownNow();

                if(!pool.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
                    logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "  ERROR: pool did not terminate");
                }
            }   
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
             // (Re-)Cancel if current thread also interrupted
             pool.shutdownNow();
             // Preserve interrupt status
             Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); 
           }
       }

  }//end class
```

I'm trying to shut my pool down safely and gracefully without running into the risk of not ever terminating. I need to understand something from you experts 8-). When I call `shutdownAndAwaitTermination()`, I'm confused about the `if (!pool.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS))` block. When that line exectues in method `go()`, does the application wait for 60 seconds before existing from the system (wait for termination) ?

2) can you explain what happens in the catch block  ?

Answer (score 1):

1) Nope it will wait at max 60 seconds, but could also return after 30 seconds if all tasks have finished.

2) If the current thread was interrupted you tell the thred pool to shutdown now, leaving the executing tasks executing. Than you interrupt again in order to preserve the thread property

Comment: 1) so `awaitTermination()` is like a while loop that check for termination within the 60 seconds ?

2) would you say this is dangerous ?

Comment: 1) While implementation defined you would generally expect the thread to sleep and not hotspin. 2) I have not seen this idiom before and thus cannot say if it's save. Looks a bit hackish